# Publicly available faces dataset with height and weight metadata

Tags: data-request, images, faces

Are there any publicly available faces database where each face is annotated with the person's height and weight?

There is the [MORPH](http://www.faceaginggroup.com/morph/) dataset but it is not publicly available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing to get your hands dirty, there are plenty of websites out there that post mugshots of arrested individuals.  Many of these come with height and weight attributes.  With a little scraping you could have as many photos as you could possibly want.  You might have to deal with watermarks and artifact removal though.

As an example, [here is a collection of mugshots from Polk County Iowa](http://data.desmoinesregister.com/iowa-mugshots/).  It even allows filtering by height, weight, age and gender.

Comment: nice! i would check local newspapers/media as well